# WPF: Image Path doesn't work after publishing

Tags: wpf, path, trayicon

I have a trayicon in my WPF App. When I was debugging in Visual Studio, it works well:
`System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
ni.Icon = new Icon("../../logo,ico");`

But after I published it, the App threw an exception saying it could find the path of the image of the trayicon. I've search a lot resources on online, I saw many solutions use pack, but it seems pack only accept Uri variable and the path for trayicon must be string. I also tried to create a folder called Resource under the project solution and put the image file into it. This was the same: worked while debugging but would not work after publishing..

So based on @WPF Germany's suggestion, I solved the path issue after publishing the App by Clickonce. However, if I copy a App shortcut to system startup folder, it would find the ico in C:\WINDOWS\system32, which is not easy to workaround since systems32 usually requires admin right to access. Any idea for that?

Comment: Why don't you add an Icon to the Resources.resx file of your Visual Studio project and load it by `ni.Icon = Properties.Resources.Logo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check, that your logo.ico file is copied to output path?

In VS you have multiple options to provide your Resource files.

**First option:**

Select your logo.ico file in solution explorer and choose `None` as `Build Action` and `Copy always` at `Copy to Output Directory` (at file properties).

After compiling you will find the file in a subdirectory of our `OutputPath`.

use (if logo.ico is placed in your projects root):

```
ni.Icon = new Icon("logo.ico");
```

**other option:**

Use `Resource` as `Build Action` and build your Icon using a `Stream` created from `Resources.logo`...

Comment: Thank you it works! But it seems like this only works in c#. If I also need the logo.ico in other xaml files, I need to import the image again with a different name. But anyway it works!

Comment: I had same problem, and I was able to fixed only when I unchecked(set to False) the 'PublishSingleFile'.